# Header location redirect not changing domain with rewrite

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

We've got a page that needs to redirect to another one. Normally, this is a relatively straightforward thing. However, the page we are redirecting to is on another domain. The page:

[www.oursite.com/our-page.php](http://www.oursite.com/our-page.php)

needs to redirect to http://www.example.com/another-page.php

normally this is a simple affair in php.

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/another-page.php");
die();
```

right? I've done it hundreds of thousands of times. But in this one case, we are arrive in our-page.php via an IIS rewrite rule. Now, when you hit the page, the browser goes off to

[www.oursite.com/another-page.php](http://www.oursite.com/another-page.php)

No matter what I put into the location header, it sticks to [www.oursite.com](http://www.oursite.com). I know the header is definitely being set, it's not giving me any header not set warnings, and it is trying to go to another-page.com.

Is there some cross domain restriction to the location header I'm not aware of? I've not been able to find anything online. The page redirects fine in any other case, just not with the rewrite rule

IIS rule is:

```
<rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">

  <match url="^test/(.*)$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/our-page.php/?path={R:1}}" />

</rule>
```

There was more going on, but I've stripped back the code to nothing but setting the location header.

What I expect to happen is I go to http://www.oursite.com/test/some-path. That gets rewritten to http://www.oursite.com/our-page/?path=some-path, which in turn gets the header set and the user ends up on http://www.example.com/another-page.php.

What actually happens is the user ends up on http://www.oursite.com/another-page.php (and then bumped again to our 404 page because that does not exist)

Comment: Your IIS rule does not seem to have anything wrong. But "which in turn gets the header set and the user ends up on http://www.example.com/another-page.php" is done by `our-page.php`. So are you sure that PHP page works correctly?

Comment: I suggest you use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Comment: @LexLi yep. I reduced the php code down to a bare minimum, just the redirect, nothing else, and the problem still occurred. Tried it without the redirect rule, and it worked. WIth. It didn't.

After a few weeks of tearing my hair out, I did arrive at a solution: I moved the entire app to an Apache server, and converted the rule to a .htaccess. Not it all works perfectly.

Not the ideal resolution, but I'll leave it up in case anyone else has the issue and this is an option.

Answer (score 0):

After a few weeks of head scratching and frantic googling. I ended up with a rather crude solution.

I moved the app from the IIS servers to Apache ones, and translated the rules to .htaccess equivalents. Possibly not the ideal solution, as that may not be an option available to everyone, but after I did that, I had no more issues.